# hiding part of a git repo from untrusted users

Tags: git, version-control

I'm trying to use git in a way that keeps some subdirectories in a project secret/hidden from "untrusted" users, but visible to other "trusted" users. Note that this is not just write protection; the untrusted users can't be allowed to read the secret files either. I'd like the user experience to be as if it was a single git repo, rather than something like submodules.

I'll tell you my only idea so far, in case that spurs some discussion or criticism. I'm considering having two parallel repos behind the scenes on the server. Trusted users clone/pull/push the trusted repo. Untrusted users clone/pull/push the untrusted repo. When a commit is made to the trusted repo, it is filtered to remove secret content before being applied to the untrusted repo. Going the other direction, commits to the untrusted repo are filtered to avoid clobbering secret content before being applied to the trusted repo.

How should I accomplish this goal?
Is my proposed solution crazy?

Comment: I went with the "hack git yourself" answer, as it is the only one that would give the simple user experience I wanted. It wasn't easy, and I had to hire an experienced contributor to the git project to make it happen. Big picture, he did it with git hooks and a separate repository for each permission set. At least it didn't require changing git source code. After a few months of use, it is working, and it is simple for users. I do worry it might be a bit fragile, and live in constant fear of my next push fouling it up. I can't say I'd recommend this route for others, but it does what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably technically possible, assuming you plan to hack `git` itself. A few questions you'll need to answer:

- How will you identify the "secret" files during pushes to the server?
- How will you ensure you are connecting to *your* server? Since no other server will filter properly, pushing to the wrong server would share all of the secret content.

If you hack git, all things are possible.

Comment: "Secret" files can be identified because they are in a directory that is identified (in some config file) as being secret. Or something like that. As for ensuring it's my server, I think I'll just have to trust the trusted users to not push it where they shouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible and a regular demand.

To do that, you should split your repo to some different repos, and use `git submodule` to combine theme to a single repo. Then you close read permission of secret repo to untrusted user.

For example, my home config is a public repo in github: https://github.com/perfectworks/home. You can find a `private` directory in there which is a submodule to another private git repo. Untrusted users can't get anything under this directory unless I authorize them the right.

You can find more things about `git submodule` here: http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say that you don't want to use submodules, you may want to take a look at [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree), which allows you to split off a subdirectory of a repository into its own repository, and merge back changes that were committed just to that other repository.  You could then use the structure:

```
full-repo
\
 .git
 public
 private
```

... and use `git-subtree split` to generate a branch that just represents the history of the `public` subdirectory, and fetch that branch into a newly created repository.  Then you let the privileged users clone `full-repo`, while untrusted users can only clone the new repository that represents the `public` subdirectory.  When changes are committed to the repository representing the `public` subdirectory, you can merge that history into `full-repo` by fetching into the original repository and running `git-subtree merge`.  Similarly, changes made in `full-repo` can have the part that affects `public` propagated to the split branch with `git subtree split`, and pull that branch into the split-off repository.

Note that if you want to do this, when propagating changes back to the repository representing `public`, you'll need to be very careful that you're not fetching objects that are private into the public repository.  For example, make sure that you just fetch the split-off branch, rather than everything in the repository.  I wouldn't use this approach in situation where security was critical, just in case one made a mistake of this kind.

Comment: This should have been the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to limit access to parts of a repo.

Having the secret content in a different repo and have that repo as submodule for the main one is the most straightforward way. Keeping in sync two repos that are filtered is not really feasible